# RabbitMQ crashes when I tried to send message

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am very new to `RabbitMQ`. I use Python to send a message between the `Sender.py` and `Receiver.py` (from the Rabbit tutorial). It works well if I run the `Sender.py` and `Receiver.py` independtly. However, I want to make the third file, namely, `RunToGether.py` with very very simple code:

```
import Sender, Receiver

Sender.send()

Receiver.receive()
```

and it crashes:

```
  File "/home/my_direct/Receive.py", line 50, in PV_simulator
    channel.start_consuming()

  File "/home/my_direct/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1865, in start_consuming
    self._process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  
File "/home/rmy_direct/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2026, in _process_data_events
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=time_limit)

  File "/home/my_direct/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 824, in process_data_events
    self._flush_output(common_terminator)

  File "/home/my_direct/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 514, in _flush_output

    self._impl.ioloop.poll()

  File "/home/my_direct/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 579, in poll

    self._poller.poll()

  File "/home/my_direct/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 1184, in poll

    events = self._poll.poll(self._get_max_wait())
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Please help!

Comment: I don't know your code and tutorial but you can't run it in this way because it starts only `Sender` and wait for its end to run `Receiver`. You would have to use `threading` or `multiprocessing` to run both at the same time. maybe it will be simpler to create bash script with `python Receiver.py &` `python Sender.py`. It uses `&` to start `Receiver in background so it can run `Sender` at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I do not need to run them at them same time, the sender can run 1st and then run the receiver. However, it seems that the channel.start_consuming() (from RabbitMG) is running and wait. I only can be stop by keyboard. About using Thread, yes I tried, but I still gave me  the same error. I will try to use script as  you suggested. Thank you so much.